# Run-time error '1004'? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to filter the range to exclude rows where in column K the value is equal to "March" and delete those rows. So all rows except the "March" ones will be displayed. 
The code runs well up to the point when it is trying to delete. `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells....` It gives me the run-time error 1004

```
Public Sub RemoveRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim lRow As Long

strSearch = "March"

Set ws = Sheets("January")

With ws
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
    With .Range("K1:K" & lRow)
 .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
      .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You must put **dots** on your Range statements:

```
Public Sub RemoveRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim lRow As Long

strSearch = "March"
Set ws = Sheets("January")

With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Remove any filters

        .AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows

        .Range("K1:K" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
        .Range("K2:K" & lRow).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    '~~> Remove any filters

    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

and the **.offset()** is not needed, just start at **K2**;
 the internal **With** statement is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look for `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. Just offset one row to preserve your header and delete.

```
.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
```

Only the visible .AutoFilter'ed rows will be deleted. You might want to check for the existence of rows to delete with `Application.Subtotal(103, ...)` as trying to delete rows when there aren't any to delete could result in bypassing the `.AutoFilter` and deleting all of your data..